# Why can I still use a variable after transferring ownership of it into a function?

Tags: rust, ownership

I'm trying to pick up the pieces in Rust on the "borrowing" concept.
Below is my code but I'm unable to get any borrowing error. From my understanding `prime1`'s ownership has been transferred but I can still use print on the variable.

```
fn main() {
    let prime1 = 100;
    all_prime_to(prime1);
    
    println!("{}", prime1);
}


fn prime_checker(num: u32) -> bool {
    let mut counter = 0;
    for x in 1..num {
       if num % x == 0 {
           counter += 1;
       }
    }

    counter < 2
}

// Vec is the same as arraylist in JAVA
fn all_prime_to(num: u32) -> Vec<u32> {
    let capacity = (num/3) as usize;
    let mut vec = Vec::with_capacity(capacity);

    for x in 2..num {
       if prime_checker(x){
           vec.push(x)
       }
    }

    vec
}
```

When I use the referencing method to keep the ownership of `prime1`, it still gives the same output.

Comment: This is actually just about ownership, not borrowing. The concepts are related but ownership is about values while borrowing is about references. There are no `&`s in your code, so there's no borrowing happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the following example, you can see that some primitive types (`i32` here) are implicitly copied when they are passed by value.

Some other more elaborate types (`String` here) can be explicitly cloned which can help keep the original value when passed by value.

When it comes to your own types, you have to decide whether it makes sense or not to implement `Clone` and why not `Copy`.
`Copy` is supposed to be a cheap operation (like for `i32`) that could happen implicitly without introducing too much overhead.
On the other hand, `Clone` applies to types for which it makes sense to obtain a new identical value but this operation might introduce a sensible overhead (dynamic memory allocation for example), thus an explicit call to `clone()` makes clear that this was intentional.

```rust
fn consume_i32(arg: i32) {
    println!("consuming {}", arg);
}

fn consume_string(arg: String) {
    println!("consuming {}", arg);
}

fn main() {
    let v0 = 123;
    consume_i32(v0);
    println!("{} still available", v0);
    println!("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
    let v1 = String::from("hello");
    consume_string(v1);
    // next line won't compile --> commented out
    // println!("{} still available", v1);
    println!("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
    let v2 = String::from("again");
    consume_string(v2.clone());
    println!("{} still available", v2);
}
```

Comment: See also [Should the Copy trait always be implemented if possible?](/q/46185453/3650362) Implementing `Copy` or not has no effect on code generation. (You didn't say that, but it is a common misconception)

Answer (score 3):

[`u32` is `Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u32.html#impl-Copy) which means it is copied instead of moved.

Comment: So all primitive type is Copy ?

Comment: @AndreeWijaya: Take a look at [the list](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html#implementors). I think that there are all the primitive types except `&mut T`: borrowing rules forbid to copy that.

Comment: @AndreeWijaya "Primitive type" is a Java-ism. In Rust all values are unboxed (except when explicitly annotated with some pointer type). Of the built-in types, some are `Copy` and some are not.

Comment: @trentcl pardon my phrasing but my point was to ask which are not Copy. Rodrigo pretty much cover that.